# Link MediaElement from VM to View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mediaelement

My situation is something like this:
I have a class called MediaElementPlayer which represents a video player, and acts as a ViewModel for a DataTemplate. It is based on this [idea](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73905/Silverlight-Advanced-View-Model-Style-Video-Player) with adjustments to WPF and MVVM light instead of Silverlight.
It works great, but I need to be able to maximize the video too.
For that I created a different window called FullScreenWindow, which holds a single ItemContainer to draw the video player. When I create this window, I pass it the MediaElementPlayer object from the main window. This works too.
The problem is that when the full screen window is opened, the media's position is not retained, that's because it creates a new MediaElement.
Is there a way I can take the MediaElement object I already have in mt MediaElementPlayer(VM) and draw it on the view, instead of creating a new one? That will help me retain media position across windows.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: UI control can only be a child of one parent. If you want to use the same `MediaElement` on other view, at least try to remove it from it's current view. Try it out and see if that works or other problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new MediaElement UserControl in your FullScreenWindow then use Binding to set its size: you can bind the MediaElement object actual `Size` to a property of the ViewModel MediaElementPlayer (you can update these values by creating a behaviour attached to  `SizeChanged` event of the UserControl).

Then, the ViewModel of the FullScreenWindow can set the `Size` of the its MediaElement basing on the property of the ViewModel.